# Matching exactly one whitespace inside if statement

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I'm trying to match a file right now to change the name of the file

```
tempString="hi"
end="_hi.pdf"
for c in *.pdf; do
 tempString="$(echo ${c})"
 if [[ $tempString =~ $AA[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.pdf$ ]]
  then
  echo "inside if"
  tempString="$(echo $tempString | tr -d ' ')"
  tempString=${tempString%.pdf}
  mv "%c" "$monthyear$tempString$end"
 fi
done
```

tempString is set to something like "AA 111.pdf"

i need it to match something like `AA 111.pdf` but not `AA  111.pdf` (one space instead of two spaces). I just want it to match exactly one whitespace inbetween AA and 111.

it keeps matching both of those examples or neither. i've tried \s, [\s], [:space:], [[:space:]], etc.

i've tried looking it up everywhere but to no avail. can somebody help me out?

Comment: `\w+ \d+\.\w+` Did you try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will match one (and only one) space names like `AA 111.pdf`:

```
if [[ "$tempString" =~ ^AA" "[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.pdf$ ]];
```

The trick is to [quote your spaces](http://board.issociate.de/thread/476054/bash--operator.html) inside the regex.

---

**Update:** The following code ignores the two (and more) spaces example:

```bash
tempString="AA  111.pdf"
if [[ "$tempString" =~ ^AA" "[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.pdf$ ]]; then 
    echo "yes" 
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

This prints `no`

*One-liner version:*

```
tempString="AA  111.pdf"; if [[ "$tempString" =~ ^AA" "[0-9][0-9][0-9]\.pdf$ ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

Comment: This still catches the two space example for some reason. I looked at the document and tried the old single quote method as well. I definitely tried double quoting the space before and to no avail.

Comment: Can you please run the example I added to the answer (as is) and tell me what's your result?

Comment: i didn't run your example but i did notice something else. in the 4th line, when tempString is set to ${c}. I echo'd this and it ignores extra spaces! So the code has been running correctly but the input is wrong. Why is that happening? There must be wrong with 
    tempString="$(echo ${c})"

Comment: That line is unnecessary, you can go on with `$c`, but if you rather want to continue using the `tempString` variable, the assignation `tempString="$c"` should work as well

Comment: it works!!! the first tempString line was kind of spaghetti code, the tempString="$c" fixed it. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `[a-zA-z]+ \d+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU4aM2/1)

and if you want any character before `space` use this `\w+ \d+`

and if you want any character before and after `space` use this `\w+ \w+`

if you want to take file extension into consideration you can add `\.pdf$`
at the end of any `regex` from the above

Comment: I said i'm only having a whitespace problem. The characters to the left and right don't matter. And i literally have a \.pdf$ IN MY CODE. I know what it does. this doesn't help at all.